# How to implement a JUNG graph with mixed (directed and undirected) edges?

Tags: jung

I have a GraphML file with both directed and un-directed edges. I want to read this file into a JUNG graph, but I can't find an appropriate implementation that would support graphs of mixed edge-types. Is there such an implementation? Or, any hints to implement one myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/graph/package-summary.html

Either SparseGraph or SparseMultigraph should do.